# Converting time object using Strptime()

Tags: python

I have a datetime object:

```
a1 = u'Fri, 14 Nov 2014 16:55:09 +0000'
```

Using strptime() I convert it:

```
b1 = a1.split('+')[0]
c1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(b1, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S ').date()
```

However, the result is

```
datetime.date(2014, 11, 14)
```

and it is cutting off the Hours, Minutes & Seconds. How do I write it so I include it as a datetime object?

Comment: remove `.date()`, `c1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(b1, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S ')`

Comment: ahh, than you! Copied someone else's code :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need remove `.date()` because it return only date and remove time:

```
a1 = u'Fri, 14 Nov 2014 16:55:09 +0000'

b1 = a1.split('+')[0]
c1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(b1, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S ')
print (c1)
2014-11-14 16:55:09
```